# Use PHP JSON array as ng-option in Angular.js

Tags: php, json, angularjs

I need help with angular.js and php. I need the options to be displayed as a select drop down in my angular view but for some reason its just not working. I guess the format of my json data is the problem. Please help.

JSON BELOW

```
{"states":{"1":"STATE 1","2":"STATE 2","3":"STATE 3"}}
```

ANGULAR CONTROLLER BELOW

```
.controller('StateListController', function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.selectedState = null;
        $scope.options = [];
    $http.get('http://localhost/listStates.json').then(function(resp) {
        $scope.options = resp.data;
        console.log(resp.data);
    }, function(err) {
        console.error('ERR', err);
        // err.status will contain the status code
    })
})
```

ANGULAR TEMPLATE BELOW

```
<div class="list" ng-controller="StateListController">
  <label class="item item-input item-select">
      <div class="input-label">
          State
      </div>
      <select ng-model="selectedState" ng-options="state.id as state.name for state in options">

      </select>
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is that you get `resp.data` instead of `resp.states`. Additionally, this is not right:

```
state.id as state.name for state in options
```

since the returned data in the json **is not** like:

```
{"states":[{"id":"1", "name":"State 1"}, {"id":"2", "name":"State 2"}, {"id":"3", "name":"State 3"}]}
```

What you need to put as binding is:

```
k as v for (k, v) in options
```

That's the way to iterate over object properties.

Comment: slight update to your solution. I had to use `resp.data.states` rather than `resp.states` or `resp.data`